# SFTP file system in hadoop

Tags: hadoop

Does hadoop version 2.0.0 and CDH4 have a SFTP file system in place ? I know hadoop has a support for  FTP Filesystem . Does it have something similar for sftp ? I have seen some patches submitted for the sme though couldn't make sense of them ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research , I have figured out that `hadoop` currently doesn't have a `FileSystem` written for `SFTP` . Hence if you wish to read data using SFTP channel you have to either write a `SFTP FileSystem` (which is quite a big deal , extending and overriding lots of classes and methods) , patches of which are already been developed , though not yet integrated into hadoop , else get a customized `InputFormat` that reads from `streams` , which again is not implemented in `hadoop.`

Comment: hi  RadAI - have you managed to solve this elegantly (sftp -> hdfs://) ? I am interested on this topic...

Answer (score 3):

Consider using hadoop distcp.

[Check here.](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/bigins/v1r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.biginsights.admin.doc%2Fdoc%2Fc_sftp.html) That would be something like:

```
hadoop distcp
  -D fs.sftp.credfile=/user/john/credstore/private/mycreds.prop
  sftp://myHost.ibm.com/home/biadmin/myFile/part1
  hdfs:///user/john/myfiles
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure core-site.xml is having property fs.sftp.impl set with value org.apache.hadoop.fs.sftp.SFTPFileSystem

Post this hadoop commands will work. Couple of samples are given below

1. ls command

> Command on hadoop

```
hadoop fs -ls /
```

> equivalent for SFTP

```
hadoop fs -D fs.sftp.user.{hostname}={username} -D fs.sftp.password.{hostname}.{username}={password} -ls sftp://{hostname}:22/
```

2. Distcp command

> Command on hadoop

```
hadoop distcp {sourceLocation} {destinationLocation}
```

> equivalent for SFTP

```
hadoop distcp -D fs.sftp.user.{hostname}={username} -D fs.sftp.password.{hostname}.{username}={password} sftp://{hostname}:22/{sourceLocation} {destinationLocation}
```

*Ensure you are replacing all the place holders while trying these commands.* I tried them on AWS EMR 5.28.1 which has Hadoop 2.8.5 installed on it

Answer (score 0):

So hopefully cleaning up these answers a bit into something more digestible.  Basically Hadoop/HDFS *is* capable of support SFTP, it's just not enabled by default, nor is it really documented in the core-default.xml very well.

The key configuration you need to set to enable SFTP support is:

```
     <property>
      <name>fs.sftp.impl</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.sftp.SFTPFileSystem</value>
     </property>
```

Alternatively, you can set it right at the CLI depending on your command

```
hdfs dfs \
  -Dfs.sftp.impl=org.apache.hadoop.fs.sftp.SFTPFileSystem \
  -Dfs.sftp.keyfile=~/.ssh/java_sftp_testkey.ppk \
  -ls sftp://$USER@localhost/tmp/
```

The biggest requirement is that your SSH Keyfile needs to be password-less to work.  This can be done via

```
cp ~/.ssh/mykeyfile.ppk ~/.ssh/mykeyfile.ppk.orig
ssh-keygen -p -P MyPass -N "" -f ~/.ssh/mykeyfile.ppk
mv ~/.ssh/mykeyfile.ppk ~/.ssh/mykeyfile_nopass.ppk
mv ~/.ssh/mykeyfile.ppk.orig ~/.ssh/mykeyfile.ppk
```

And finally, the biggest (and maybe neatest) is using this via distcp, if you need to send/receive a large amount of data to/from an SFTP server.  There's an oddity about the ssh keyfile being needed locally to generate the directory listing, as well as on the cluster for the actual workers.
Something like this should work well enough:

```
cd workdir
ln -s ~/.ssh/java_sftp_testkey.ppk
hadoop distcp \
  --files ~/.ssh/java_sftp_testkey.ppk \
  -Dfs.sftp.impl=org.apache.hadoop.fs.sftp.SFTPFileSystem \
  -Dfs.sftp.keyfile=java_sftp_testkey.ppk \
  hdfs:///path/to/source/ \
  sftp://user@FQDN/path/to/dest
```